# MemoryStream into MagicImage

Tags: c#, imagemagick, memorystream

I am trying to store MemoryStream into MagicImage, but when I am trying to upload file with heic format it still uploading with heic format, but it should upload it with jpeg format. So I kind of do not understand where I am doing wrong. So could someone help me? I am trying it open in Frame in web, but it does not open bc it is not converting it to jpeg.

```
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    create.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    var data = ms.ToArray();


                    byte[] data1 = null;
                    using (var image = new MagickImage(data))
                    {
                        // Sets the output format to jpeg
                        image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;

                        // Create byte array that contains a jpeg file
                        data1 = image.ToByteArray();
                    }

                    var file = new ClientFile
                    {
                        Data = data1, // here where it should store it in jpeg
                    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have never used your way of writing the image, this is what I use in my implementations and it always works:

```
var image = new MagickImage(sourceStream);
var format = MagickFormat.Jpg;
var stream = new MemoryStream();
image.Write(stream, format);
stream.Position = 0;
```

EDIT
If you don't add:

```
stream.Position = 0
```

sending the stream will not work as it will start saving from the current position which is at the end of the stream.

Comment: what is sourseStream in your case? new MagickImage(sourceStream);

Comment: @RuslanAbilkaiyrov this code is used by a library working in Azure and WPF applications.
In WPF case it's FileStream, however in Azure case, it's a MemoryStream. Both of them implement the same System.IO.Stream.

Comment: and also I need it exacly in that way how it show